# Mapping primitive type in JNA while keeping the native typedef class

Tags: java, jna

I have this type defined in my DLL:

```
typedef int FMOD_MEMORY_TYPE;
```

Can I make a class for this in Java so I will know `FMOD_MEMORY_TYPE` is just an `int`?

```
public final class FMOD_MEMORY_TYPE {
    public int value;
}
```

As I presume it takes the same amount of memory?

This type is passed into functions a lot and it would make it a lot easier if in Java it had its own typedef almost too. If not, how can I make some of mapping to a type in Java?

Essentially it's just an `int` but having to replace all occurrences with `int` would take a lot of time and this would be easier.

Essentially I Want to be able to map the code like this:
(C):

```
void some_function(FMOD_MEMORY_TYPE argument);
```

<=> Java:

```
public void some_function(FMOD_MEMORY_TYPE arg);
```

instead of:

```
public void some_function(int arg);
```

Comment: Adding an entire layer of indirection is going to make things harder.  The mapping should be obvious from the function prototypes generated in your header file.  Or you can just use `jint` or `jlong` as your primitive type in your DLL. If you don't want to do that, use fixed-width types such as `int64_t` for Java `long` since primitives in Java have fixed sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a wrapper class for primitives, but not quite as simply as you describe.

A wrapper class gives you some ease in porting code as you've requested, as well as type safety.  The class will take a little bit more memory on the Java side as you're allocating space for an entire object instead of simply the memory for a primitive. And there will be a tiny performance hit for storing and retrieving the internal value.  However, if these trade-offs are worth it to you and aren't used in a performance-sensitive application, it's not a problem.

However, you can't just use a class as you've described in your question without adding additional functionality for JNA to determine the byte size of the object and its corresponding native equivalent. Specifically, you would have to implement the `NativeMapped` interface.  This is most easily done by extending an existing JNA class which already does this work for you.

For an integer typedef, I would recommend that you create a type that extends `IntegerType` and provides you access to those methods.  So in your case, I'd do:

```
public final class FMOD_MEMORY_TYPE extends IntegerType {

    public static final int SIZE = 4; // bytes

    public FMOD_MEMORY_TYPE() {
        this(0);
    }

    public FMOD_MEMORY_TYPE(int value) {
        super(SIZE, value);
    }
}
```

Doing this will will inherit `setValue()` from `IntegerType` and inherit all of the core Java [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class methods like `intValue()`.

You could also choose to implement `Comparable` or add other methods as needed.

There are plenty of examples in JNA's [WinDef class](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef.java), among others.